# How to ask manager to reduce team size?

Tags: management, team, manager, termination, hiring

I started working for a big, multinational company a few months ago, in an intermediate (i.e. not junior) position. A few months after I joined, another member was added to the team. The new member was hired in a similar capacity as me & does not bring any skills or expertise that the team does not have already.

The new hire seemed unnecessary to me, because my team could easily manage the workload. I did not bring this up to my manager because I did not know if there would be any future business needs that would justify the hiring & because I was new. **Despite this, should I have brought this up to my manager then ?**

After a few more months, our company announced planned layoffs to become efficient. From internal information, it is highly unlikely, but not guaranteed that me & my team members would be on the layoff list. Either way, I am not worried because I can comfortably look for a new job in a new company & get one "quickly" in case I end up in the list. But, for now, I would like to stay here because I am getting to learn new things.

Now, my team's workload remains unchanged, but the individual workload has decreased significantly (say, from 40 hours per week to about 30 something). The individual workload could be improved if the team size was reduced by one team member, either by reassigning a team member to teams/projects that need people or by "downsizing". **How do I bring this up to my manager ?**

Comment: Will you be framing this as "there is duplication between our roles, one of us should go," or "there is duplication in our roles, the other person, who you hired after me, should go"?  You seem to be asking how to get a co-worker fired to better secure your own status.

Comment: *individual workload has decreased significantly* OK, but is it down from something like 60hrs a week to 40hrs a week or more like 40hrs a week to 25hrs a week? There's a difference between having some breathing room and sitting on your hands for half the work day.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - Having the co worker fired won't guarantee any security of my status. It is unlikely, but I could be on the layoff list already or might be added later. Maybe we both are in the list. Maybe the whole team is on the list.

Comment: @BSMP - Individual workload is down from 40 hours a week to about 30. It varies, but we don't stay as busy as before.

Comment: There could be several motivations. The most optimistic is that you are being considered for promotion, but they need to have someone who duplicates your skills on the team and up to speed first. They could just be looking at your team's bus factor - having an extra person lets you create backups for each role.

Comment: You and I have drastically different definitions for what "improving" a workload means. Have you even considered asking your manager about his reasons for making the hire instead of assuming that he just wanted to bring some dead weight on board? People who aren't in a management position don't get to make hiring or firing decisions for a reason.

Comment: That's fine, my comment was as much playing devil's advocate so you could address that issue, because it might be easy to look at the question in that light. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I understand its important to see issues from all sides. But, this place seems to revere managers like they are an all knowing god. Apparently, none of the people here have encountered managers who either indulge in nepotism or just try to build a bigger team to look better (i.e. empire building)

Answer (score 14):

> The individual workload could be improved if the team size was reduced
>   by one team member, either by reassigning a team member to
>   teams/projects that need people or by "downsizing". How do I bring
>   this up to my manager ?

If you feel strongly about it, you can always volunteer to be let go.

You shouldn't suggest that others be laid off, that's not your responsibility, but you can choose to sacrifice yourself.

Answer (score 9):

> How do I bring this up to my manager?

**Don't.**

Do not bring up that the team is too big, because then you might get cut. Instead, I would ask about how you can perform better at your job so that you can stand out. Sure, the individual workload has decreased, but that means you have time now to review your work to ensure that it is flawless. In addition, you mentioned you enjoyed learning new things at your job, so why not take advantage of the time and learn new things? There's a chance that in a few months a major project will come up and you won't have as much time as you do now.

Comment: Yes, there is a risk that my suggestion will be used to remove me and even others too.

Comment: If the person has been brought in for a good reason, then no need to worry. If not, then it will be bad for you especially during financial down turns. So you'd better use the free time to prepare for interviews. Use your manager's move against them. When you have an offer, then ask the manager about the new person. If it makes sense, then maybe continue. Otherwise, quit and don't waste your time on the exit interview.

Answer (score 4):

### It isn't your job

Your manager's job is resource planning and he/she has probably already begun that planning.

It is not your job.

You would likely offend your manager with your suggestion - especially if you bring up the fact that you don't believe the new person should have been hired in the first place.

In other words, that conversation will give the impression that you think your manager is dumber than you.

And, if your manager is left with that impression, there is a high chance of ***you*** being put on the "lay off" list, not the other person.